# Change case across 1.5 million lines by Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to change the case from UPPER to lower (A..Z to a..z) in the selected block of text column (the 2nd-33rd characters of each line, inclusive) of 1.5 million lines in Notepad++. I can select, but whenever I right click, lowercase, then it just hangs on forever.

Is there a way to solve this problem differently?
**From** this:

```
"63FA41D10F5902EA58AEFGBAF02A4E32"...
```

**To** this:

```
"63fa41d10f5902ea58aefgbaf02a4e32"...
```

in 1.5 million lines.

Comment: Clearly it doesn't *hang on forever*, or you'd still be waiting. 1.5m lines is a lot of text, and you've complicated things by doing it in column mode. How long **specifically** did you want for it to get done? Why do you have to do it in Notepad++? Have you tried writing some code to do it in the language of your choice?

Comment: i can wait an hour but not much more. yes if Npp is not an option then i guess python.

Comment: You've tried it in Python? My question was *Have you tried writing some code?* This isn't a code writing service. Make an effort to do something other than use Notepad++, and then you can ask a question about something else.

Comment: i am asking about an error in a **built-in function** of npp.  yes there are many non-npp solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to convert with regex, it took approx 1min for 1.5 Mlines

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.\K.{32}`
- Replace with: `\L$0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  .         : 1 any character but newline
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  .{32}     : 32 any character but newline
```

**Replacement:**

```
\L          : convert to lowercase
$0          : the whole match (ie. 32 characters after the first one)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you selected  the Text in column mode from note Notepad++ and  you can press shift+ctrl+U  --> selected text will be in Upper case

if you want to change it lower case, just press Ctrl+U.

I hope this will help.
if you are using older version, try to use latest version.

Thanks,
Thangamani Eraniyan.

Comment: Thank you. As I wrote above, I tried with mouse click (works perfectly on smaller dataset). The problem is with the huge number of lines it never gets done and just keeps waiting for 30 min (I gave up).

Comment: This is no different than what the poster is doing in the question. It's the same functionality. It's irrelevant whether you get there from the keyboard or the right-click context menu with the mouse; it's the same code that is executed. This answer contributes nothing.

Comment: i understand, it may due to the Memory capacity, you may wanted to use scripting like vbscript, python or powershell to read each line and convert uppercase for desire position and save it on other file, its would be easy and faster.    if you want i can give you vb script, let me know. thanks -thangamani eraniyan

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
set fin = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fout = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileinput = fin.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\TestFile\TestFile1.txt",1,1) 
Set fileoutput = fout.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\TestFile\ResultFile.txt",2,1) 
Do Until fileinput.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = fileinput.ReadLine
    strlineout = left(strLine,1) + ucase(mid(strLine, 2, 32)) + mid(strLine,33)
    fileoutput.Write(strLine)
Loop
fileoutput.Close
fileinput.Close
fout.Close
fin.Close
```

Thangamani Eraniyan